Can the morphisms between stalks uniquely determine the morphisms between sheaves
As we all know, morphism between sheaves $\varphi: F \rightarrow G$ induces morphism between stalks $\varphi_{x}: F_{x} \rightarrow G_{x}$ through $\varphi_{x}(U, s) = (U, \varphi(U)(s))$. But if, on the other hand, for any point $x$, given the stalks morphism $f_{x}: F_{x} \rightarrow G_{x}$, can we construct a sheaf morphism $\varphi: F \rightarrow G$ s.t. $\varphi_{x} = f_{x}$. If not, how to modify the conditions and restrict $f_{x}$ to make the conclusion valid. 
My Attempt: $\prod_{x \in U}f_{x}: \prod F(U) = \prod_{x \in U}F_{x} \rightarrow \prod G(U)$ is morphism between $\prod F$ and $\prod G$.  Consider $F$ as a subsheaf of $\prod F$, but I can't prove that $\prod_{x \in U}f_{x}(F(U)) \subseteq G(U)$. Is this idea wrong? Thank you very much for any hints and proofs.

Yes, the morphisms on stalks uniquely determine the morphism of sheaves. This can be seen as follows:
Let $\psi, \varphi: F \to G$ be two morphisms, such that for each $x \in X$, the morphisms $\psi_x$ and $\varphi_x$ are the same. Then their difference $\psi - \varphi$ induces the zero-morphism on each stalk. But a morphism that is pointwise zero is the zero morphism, hence $\psi - \varphi = 0$. $\square$
However, you cannot just prescribe arbitrary morphisms on stalks and expect them to yield a morphism of sheaves. There has to be some compatibility. Suppose you have a morphism $\varphi: F \to G$, and you know that over a point $x \in X$, you have
$$\varphi_x(U,f) = (V,g) \in G_x.$$
Here $U$ and $V$ are open neighbourhoods of $x$. From this it follows that on some open neighbourhood $W \subset U \cap V$, you have
$$\varphi_W(f|_W) = \varphi_W(g|_W),$$
where $\varphi_W: F(W) \to G(W)$ comes from the morphism of sheaves. But this means that for every $y \in W$, you also have $\varphi_y(f) = g_y$. So the morphism $\varphi_y$ cannot be arbitrary.
This might be a bit abstract. Try to think of the following example. On $X = \mathbb R$, let $F = G = C^0$ be the sheaf of continous functions, i.e. $C^0(U) = \{\, f: U \to \mathbb R \text{ continuous} \,\}$. Set
$$\varphi_x(f) = \begin{cases}f &\text{if } x \neq 0 \\ 0 & \text{if } x = 0\end{cases}$$
Can you show that this does not define a morphism of sheaves?

Thank you very much for your example, but I still want to ask what conditions need to be imposed on the stalk morphism in order to glue it into a sheaf morphism. In your example, it seems to indicate that the stalk morphism needs to satisfy conditions similar to sheafification. Is that so, or can there be stronger or weaker conditions.
